# JqGrid is called during page load but next time when am calling it on button click it is not getting called

Tags: jqgrid

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        BindGrid('', '', '', '', 1, 2, '', '', sessionStorage.UserID);

    });
    function Search() {
        $('#modal_Advance_Search').modal('hide');
        var channelselected = $('#dd_channel option:selected');
        var channelarray = [];
        $(channelselected).each(function (index, channelsel) {
            channelarray.push([$(this).val()]);
        });
        var Channel = channelarray.toString();

        var Distselected = $('#dd_dist_category option:selected');
        var Distarray = [];
        $(Distselected).each(function (index, channelsel) {
            Distarray.push([$(this).val()]);
        });
        var DistributorCategory = Distarray.toString();

        var ARNNo = "";
        var token = $("#txt_arn").tokenInput("get");
        var names = [];

        $.each(token, function (i, obj) {
            names.push(obj.name);//build an array of just the names
        });
        ARNNo = names.toString();

        sessionStorage.setItem("DistributorCategoryMaster", DistributorCategory);
        sessionStorage.setItem("ChannelCreateMaster", Channel);
        sessionStorage.setItem("ARNCreateMaster", ARNNo);

        sessionStorage.setItem("ismasterqueue", true);

        $("#hdr_name").text("Master Q");

        $("#spn_user_name").text(sessionStorage.UserName);
        $("#spn_role_name").text(sessionStorage.RoleName);

        BindGrid(ARNNo, Channel, '', DistributorCategory, 1, 2, Utility.ListSearchText, '', sessionStorage.UserID)

    }
    function BindGrid(ArnNo1, Channel1, ARNName1, DistributorCategory1, Status1, MasterQueueStatus1, SearchFilter1, MemoLevel1, UserID1) {


        $("#tbl_masterqueue").jqGrid({

            url: "/Pages/MSQ.aspx/GetCreateBaseRackRate",

            mtype: 'POST',
            postData:
            {
                ArnNo: ArnNo1, Channel: Channel1, ARNName: ARNName1, DistributorCategory: DistributorCategory1, Status: Status1, MasterQueueStatus: MasterQueueStatus1, SearchFilter: SearchFilter1, MemoLevel: MemoLevel1, UserID: UserID1

            },
            datatype: "json",
            ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
            serializeGridData: function (postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                root: function (obj) { return obj.d; }
            },
            colNames: ['Select', 'Memoid', 'Memo Number', 'Memo Type', 'Memo Type ID', 'Category', 'ARN No', 'ARN Name', 'Date From', 'Date To', 'Status', 'Status', 'Raised By', 'Raised On', 'Time', 'Ageing', 'Last Action By', 'Pending With'],
            colModel: [
                    { name: 'edi', index: 'edi', formatter: MasterQueue.ReturnRadioBox, width: '60px;', disabled: true, hidden: true, sortable: false },
                     { name: 'PaymentMemoId', index: 'PaymentMemoId', width: 120, hidden: true, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'MemoNumber', index: 'MemoNumber', align: 'center', formatter: MasterQueue.ReturnSearchHyperLink, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'MemoTypeName', index: 'MemoTypeName', width: 120, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'MemoTypeID', index: 'MemoTypeID', hidden: true, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'DistributorCategoryName', index: 'DistributorCategoryName', width: 260, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'ARNNo', index: 'ARNNo', width: 90, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'ARNName', index: 'ARNName', width: 260, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'DateFrom', index: 'DateFrom', sorttype: "date", align: 'center', width: 90, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'DateTo', index: 'DateTo', align: 'center', width: 90, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'MemoStatus', index: 'MemoStatus', align: 'center', width: 90, hidden: true, sortable: false },
                     { name: 'MemoStatusDisplay', index: 'MemoStatusDisplay', align: 'center', width: 90, sortable: false },
                    { name: 'CreatedByName', index: 'CreatedByName', align: 'left', sortable: false },
                    { name: 'RaisedOnDate', index: 'RaisedOnDate', width: 90, align: 'center', sortable: false },
                    { name: 'RaisedOnTime', index: 'RaisedOnTime', width: 50, align: 'center', sortable: false },
                    { name: 'Ageing', index: 'Ageing', width: 70, align: 'right', sortable: false },
                    { name: 'ModifiedByName', index: 'ModifiedByName', align: 'left', sortable: false },
                     { name: 'PendingWith', index: 'PendingWith', align: 'left', sortable: false },
            ],
            rowNum: 100,
            rowList: [100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
            pager: '#pager',
            sortname: 'PaymentMemoId',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            gridview: true,
            height: '510px',
            loadonce: true,
            gridview: true

        });
        jQuery("#tbl_masterqueue").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: true, refresh: true },
                   {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, showQuery: true });
    }
```

I have created one method to bind grid during pageload,its working fine but again when am calling the same method during filtering/searching on button click this method is not working.I am using JQGrid,please help to fix.

Comment: I am assuming there are problems with the parameters you are giving to the function BindGrid inside the Search. Debug using a developer tools and find out.

Comment: i was also thinking the same and tested my parameters many times,i don't think problem is with parameter values,i think there is an issue with re initialization of JQGrid ,am not sure.

Comment: Finally i solved the issue , kudos to me. Don't use 'loadonce: true' It will load your grid only once.So either makes it false or better not to use.